# How do I link to a specific section of an iBook from an iBook HTML Widget?

Tags: epub, ibook-author

I am creating an HTML widget in the new iBooks Author format(.iba) that will be able to link to content within the book. In the epub3 format, I would just link to an .xhtml page that contains the content, but since the new .iba format is flow-able and there are no actual pages, how can I link to content within the book?

I discovered an article(http://www.tameri.com/wordpress/2012/02/23/some-thoughts-in-ibooks-author/) that mentioned linking to some element on the page with a specific ID, but I am not sure how to get the ID onto an element in iBooks Author.

How do I link to a specific section of an iBook from an iBook HTML Widget?

Answer (score 1):

I think we can't (using iBA). It runs in separate content container kind of "black box". The content does not exist unless user tap widget container (image, etc) and it popups.
Request feature:
http://www.apple.com/feedback/ibooks-author.html
I do not know solutions use reversed-enginered format,
Consider that HTML widget can be run in sandbox at runtime in iPad runtime for security reasons (as this is active content and could read/load content from web) - so I would make sure that my time is spent for researching solution that would work.
regards,
Peter